# Distinct value is not coming in query

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have this query

```
select distinct Name,ID from tbl_abc where Name like '%william jam%'
```

My expected result is

```
Anderson William James   1
William James            2
```

and the result coming is

```
Anderson William James   1
William James            2
William James            3
```

The data present inside table is

```
Anderson William James   1
William James            2
William James            3
```

how can i achieve this. I am trying this from last 2 hours but not getting distinct name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Name,ID
 from tbl_abc where Name like '%william jam%'
group by Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve using `GROUP BY` and if you want ID of the latest record use `MAX` and for first use `MIN` of same names

For max

```
select Name, MAX(ID) from tbl_abc where Name like '%william jam%' GROUP BY Name
```

For min

```
select Name, MIN(ID) from tbl_abc where Name like '%william jam%' GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: +1 I much prefer the explicit nature of selecting the `ID` over whatever MySQL decides to return because `ID` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: but in either way if we use `ID` it will give a min value.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - not always. When you don't use an aggregate function on `ID` and let MySQL implicit select a value for you, it will return the first `ID` for each `Name` it encounters.

Comment: @Lieven yes , so it directly means the minimum ID (in auto increment column).

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - you can't guarantee that it will always return the minimum ID, to make it sure you have to have use `MIN`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - In an auto increment column in the current implementation of MySQL I believe it will but you are relying on a **DBMS specific feature** that will sooner or later come back to bite you. Imagine someone updating the ID *(in SQL Server that's possible so I assume it will be possible in MySQL)* or altering its column definition or ... Being explicit about it 1) works in all DBMS's I know of and 2) has no performance penalty to speak of compared to the implicit version and most importantly 3) is **always** correct.

Comment: @Lieven I totally agree with you. But ID is primary key in this table.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar - Oh for heavens sake, do as you please. I give up ;)

Comment: @Lieven sorry I give up . You don't give up.Because you are absolutely right :)